# org.eclipse.m2e.core plugin hitting NullPointerException in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2e

Imported a maven project in Eclipse Oxygen and am hitting this issue with **org.eclipse.m2e.core** plugin when building the project. m2e version is 1.8.3, anybody know why this happens? I have seen similiar issues in bug reports from way back but they were marked as fixed from version 1.1 onwards.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.model.PluginExecutionMetadata.getAction(PluginExecutionMetadata.java:144)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.isConfigurator(LifecycleMappingFactory.java:718)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.calculateEffectiveLifecycleMappingMetadata0(LifecycleMappingFactory.java:602)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.calculateEffectiveLifecycleMappingMetadata(LifecycleMappingFactory.java:535)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.calculateEffectiveLifecycleMappingMetadata(LifecycleMappingFactory.java:249)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.LifecycleMappingFactory.calculateLifecycleMapping(LifecycleMappingFactory.java:181)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.setupLifecycleMapping(ProjectRegistryManager.java:594)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:513)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:492)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:496)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:351)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:298)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:154)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:89)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
```

Furthermore if you actually go and try to check out the code here:

https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core/tree/m2e-1.8.x/org.eclipse.m2e.core/src/org/eclipse/m2e/core/internal/lifecyclemapping

this package doesn't even seem to exist? WTH is going on here? Has this project been forked to hell and I'm looking in the wrong place? Should I just pack up and start using IntelliJ, seems like m2e has become unmanageable in Eclipse. The lifecyclemapping is defined as such in a parent

```
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          <pluginExecutions>
            <pluginExecution>
              <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <versionRange>[2.10,)</versionRange>
                <goals>
                  <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
              </pluginExecutionFilter>
            </pluginExecution>
          </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PluginExecutionMetadata is generated from [lifecycle-mapping-metadata-model.xml](https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core/blob/89cd40ba907e178d523f40ac22f7eac0291de37b/org.eclipse.m2e.core/mdo/lifecycle-mapping-metadata-model.xml) using [modello](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/modello/modello-maven-plugin/)

The line in the generated code where the NPE happens is

```
org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom actionDom = ((org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom) getActionDom()).getChild(0);
```

This points to the answer: In your xml snippet, the required `<action>` tag is missing, e.g. like:

```
             </pluginExecutionFilter>
             <action>
               <ignore/>
             </action>
           </pluginExecution>
```

Comment: I've already added <execute/> or <ignore/> here and am still seeing the same issue during the build. I'm suspecting that maybe Eclipse is caching the pom, but clearing out .metadata or the project files doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Have you increased the version of the parent pom?

Comment: I haven't actually changed the parent pom at all, I added this config in the child pom to overwrite the behaviour in the parent pom (where action was not specified). I'm looking at the effective pom and it seems to show the action present, but am still getting null pointer.

Comment: I'd check if the NPE goes away if the broken parent pom is not mentioned in the pom.

Comment: Yep, if I remove the reference to the parent pom the m2e null pointer does indeed go away. It seems like even though I overwrite the lifecycle mapping in the child pom the parent pom still gets read (which TBF you'd expect it to) and the NullPointer occurs/m2e build fails. Seems like the only way to fix this is to fix the parent pom unfortunately.

Comment: Another thing I'd point out though is that this was supposed to have been fixed a long time ago - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371618 -  but the current version of m2e(1.8.3) used by Eclipse Oxygen is still hitting this bug, presumably due to the forked nature of m2e.

Comment: While you were writing this, I've reopened https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=387736

Comment: The NPE will be fixed in m2e 1.9 (for Eclipse Photon)